# Yii2: how to change date format in 2amigos yii2-date-picker-widget?

Tags: date, datepicker, yii2

I am using [DatePicker widget by 2amigos](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget) to show a date with the format **dd/mm/yyyy** but there is a problem with the date format.

I open the **Yii2 Create** form:

[image: Without a date yet]

Then I choose a date and it works perfect:

[image: With a date]

But the problem is when I open the **Yii2 Update** file. The format is not right:

[image: Format yyyy-mm-dd instead of dd/mm/yyyy]

This is my datepicker code in my `_form.php` file:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'fecfinsubr')->widget(dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker::className(), [
    'clientOptions' => [
        'format' => 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    ]
]) ?>
```

The variable's content is stored in a PostgreSQL database with the format yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either provide the formatted date for the column `fecfinsubr` before you send the model object to the view or override `afterFind()` in the model to format and override the date in the desired format.

I would go for the second one.

```
public function afterFind()
{
    parent::afterFind();
    $date = new \DateTime($this->fecfinsubr);

    $this->fecfinsubr = $date->format('d/m/Y');
}
```